# Maximizing the line integral $\int \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$ for the vector field $\mathbf{F}=\langle x^2 y+y^3-y,3x+2y^2 x+e^y\rangle$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> 1. Consider the vector field $\mathbf{F}=\langle x^2 y+y^3-y,3x+2y^2 x+e^y\rangle$. For which closed non-self-intersecting curve in the plane does the line integral over this vector field have the maximal value? What is this value?
> 2. Let $\mathbf{F}=\langle xy,y^2\rangle$, let $C$ be the unit circle centered at the origin, and consider $\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$. Which portions of $C$ contribute positively to this integral? Calculate the integral two ways, first directly and then by using Green's theorem.

For the first question. I need to maximize the line integral  how do I do that?
How can I apply Maxima minima concept to this?

Comment: My first idea is to apply Green's theorem.

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: If the curve is negatively oriented, the maximum is infinity.

Comment: @Maxim Edited my answer to include that case. Though I believe that in most introductory calculus textbooks it is stated in the beginning of a section that you can assume all curves are positively oriented unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Assuming that the desired curve $C$ is positively oriented (otherwise the maximum does not exist), by Green's theorem (we can do this, since $C$ is a simple closed curve), we have that:
$$\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\oint_C (x^2 y+y^3-y)~dx+(3x+2y^2 x+e^y)~dy=\iint_D (4-x^2-y^2)~dx~dy$$
Where in the $x$-$y$ plane is the integrand non-negative? So, what should you take the region $D$ to be so that the integral is maximal? And what does that imply for $C=\partial D$?

Comment: I guess a circle with centre origin and radius $\sqrt 2$ units ?

Comment: You almost got it! The radius should be different ($x^2+y^2=r^2$ is a circle of radius $r$). And don't forget to specify the orientation of the curve you take (positively or negatively oriented).

Comment: Why radius is different? We need to maximize $(4-r^2)\pi r^2$ and I am getting root 2

Comment: I guess radius should be 2.

Comment: Yes, the radius should be $2$, not $\sqrt{2}$. Only positive contributions to the integrand will increase the value of the line integral. The region such that the integrand is positive is $x^2+y^2\leq 4$, hence $C$ should be the set of points such that $x^2+y^2=4=2^2$.

Comment: By the way, if you want to compute the integral, you'd want to either parametrize the curve and solve the line integral, or use polar coordinates on the double integral (much easier, IMHO).