# Let $F=\langle xy^2, 3z-xy^2, 4y-x^2y\rangle$ Find the maximum value of the line integral of $F$ over a simply closed curve C in the plane $x+y+z=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

Let $F=(xy^2, 3z-xy^2, 4y-x^2y)$ . Find the maximum value of the line integral of F over a simply closed curve $C$ in the plane $x+y+z=1$. What is the curve that maximises it?

I am a bit confused on how to approach this question. I tried parameterising $C$ which clearly didn't help as I needed two parameters to do so.

I then tried using Stokes theorem. I took out the dot product of the curl and the normal vector which came out to be $1-x^2+2x-y^2-2xy $ but I don't know how to proceed further. What substitution would we make?

Answer (score 1):

This question is actually solvable using Stoke's theorem. You made a mistake when calculating the curl.

The curl should be $<1-x^2, 2xy, -y^2-2xy>$. Considering the plane $x+y+z=1$, we take $<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}>$ as the unit normal vector.

Then,
$$\oint_{C}{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}} = \iint_{S}{(\triangledown\times \vec{F})\cdot \hat{n} dS} = \iint_{S}{\frac{1-x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{3}}dS}$$

There's another post talking about maximizing a line integral. You may check for more ideas [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347007/maximizing-the-line-integral-int-mathbff-cdot-d-mathbfr-for-the-vector-f). Basically the idea is using polar coordinates and come to a conclusion that $C$ should be a circle with radius 1. Hope this helps!